# Timer Tick in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, timer

whats is the equivalent of these in asp? 
it doesn't work for me!

```
lbl_date.Text = FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.LongDate)
lbl_time.Text = FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.LongTime)
```

Comment: What is the relation between your title ("timer tick") and the question (set label text)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to remember here is that all your vb code does is generate an html document, and *nothing else*. Once that job is done, the page class you're working in is even sent off to the garbage collector and the processor thread you were in is repurposed to serve another http request.  Therefore trying to set a label based on a timer event is just plain nuts — your timer will likely be disposed before it ever has a chance to tick.

Instead, you want to do this particular job in javascript. Look into javascript's setTimeout() method.

Answer (score 2):

```
lbl_date.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
lbl_time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no Timer control in ASP.NET as such, but AJAX timer.

In that case you have to put these labels inside AJAX update panel as follows

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_date" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_time" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and in code behind for `Timer1_Tick` event put

```
lbl_date.Text = FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.LongDate)
lbl_time.Text = FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.LongTime)
```

this should work..